# Align elements vertical with diffrent VerticalAlignments

Tags: c#, wpf

I' having this situation:

```
<DockPanel>
        <ListView DockPanel.Dock="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="auto">

        </ListView>
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Button Content="1" Height="30" Width="30" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="bottom" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Button  Content="2" Height="30" Width="30" />
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
```

I want that Button 1 and Button 2 align vertical.

In my actual code instead of Button 1 I have multiple textboxes with labels and Button 2 are multiple Buttons wich should be at right bottom corner of the window but when the window is to small the textboxes overlapp with the buttons.

I couldn't find a solution for that so I trying to find the core problem.

Comment: Shouldn't the last `Grid` be docked at `Right` then? Anyway, I don't see your problem. Whatever I do, the button's won't overlap.

Comment: For my actual problem yes but I think its the same problem. The buttons overlapp when the window gets resized and gets to small.

Comment: @Sumexx Can you pls post a diagram which shows how the UI should be rendered? The flaw I can see in the code is that you have not set `MinWidth` or `MinHeight` in any of the controls

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Please post a screenshot and your environment if the above code does not give correct results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make this work:

```
<DockPanel>
    <ListView DockPanel.Dock="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="auto">

    </ListView>
    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Button Content="1" Height="30" Width="30" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="bottom" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Button  Content="2" Height="30" Width="30" />
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Put an additional DockPanel around the grids and make the grids dock Top and Bottom.